# facebook request_uri not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

The invitation dialog pops up fine and invitation is also sent. But i am unable to redirect the user to desired page after sending the invitation using redirect_uri as stated in Requests Dialog facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). There is no redirection or anything after sending invitation.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init({
        appId  : 'app_id',
      });
      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'Invite friends!',
          request_uri: 'https://apps.facebook.com/myappname/invitesent.php', data: '<?php echo $user_id; ?>', exclude_ids: [<?php echo $friends; ?>]
        }, requestCallback);
      }
      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is request_uri ? do you mean redirect_uri?  (Also, that shouldn't be needed unless you're opening the dialog full screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `redirect_uri` if you are using the JS-SDK. This is the job of the callback function, so in your `requestCallback()`:

```
function requestCallback(response) {
    // Handle callback here
    ...


    // once done, redirect (outside of Facebook page!)
    top.location.href = 'http://mydomain.com/nextpage/';
}
```

Or I suppose `location.href = '';`  to stay in the Facebook app frame.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already included Facebook javascript SDK in your App
and you have writen this code for inviting friend for your App in a script

```
 FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        redirect_uri: 'APP URL',   
         message: 'My Message' 
    });
```

This will redirect to App URL without redirecting to Facebook canvas URL.So this will not work even if you use data parameter such as

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
    data: 'APP URL',   
     message: 'My Message' 
});
```

Write this code at your App landing page i.e. in index.php at beginning of the code.

```
$requestid=$_GET[request_ids];    
if(!empty($requestid))
    {       
        echo "<script> window.top.location.href='APP URL'; </script>";                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given callback canvas url when you create facebook application?

Comment: I have defined Canvas Url which is the link to the place where the application is hosted. I haven't defined any de-authorization callback url which i assumed was when user removes my application. I can't find as to where was i supposed to define callback canvas url in the application settings

Comment: when you create your facebook application, there you would see link called "App on Facebook" there you can find "Canvas url", this is the url which redirects the facebook app once you login to facebook using your application.

Comment: Yes 'Canvas URL' is defined as i said earlier. Thats why the application is running fine.